# Триггер для MySql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица "vizits", в ней есть поля date и weeks. Хочу сделать триггер? чтобы при добавлении в таблицу, поле weeks высчитывало номер недели с поля date:

```
 update vizits
 set weeks = weekofyear(date)
```

Подскажите, как это сделать, никогда не делал. Пробовал по мануалу, не катит:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `vizits`.`after_insert_date`
AFTER INSERT ON `vizits` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
update vizits set weeks = weekofyear(date);
END
```

Comment: Учимся пользоваться [гуглом][1], вопрос-то из документации!


  [1]: http://www.google.by/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mysql+triggers

Comment: а что именно не катит ?

Comment: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CREATE TRIGGER insert_date before INSERT ON vizits FOR EACH ROW begin set new.weeks = weekofyear(new.date) end;

Comment: Не хочет:
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 1

VERSION(): 5.1.37-1ubuntu5.5

Comment: delimiter //;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_date before INSERT ON vizits FOR EACH ROW begin set new.weeks = weekofyear(new.date) end;

Comment: Таки работает, триггер добавился без проблем... но теперь при добавлении ругается вот так: /* SQL Error (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vizits`.`vizits`, CONSTRAINT `FK_vizits_doctor` FOREIGN KEY (`doctor_id`) REFERENCES `doctor` (`id`)) */
Но при этом всеровно работает)

Comment: Разобрался, таки все ок))) СПС огромное. СПС

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/mysql-man-5.0-en/introduction.html#constraints
http://androschuk.blogspot.com/2011/05/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update.html

Ошибка не в триггере. По идее без триггера была бы она же.

Answer (score 0):

Невозможно производить операции с той же таблицей, на которой сработал триггер.
Попробуйте переписать триггер используя "before", и менять не запись в таблице, а данные перед вставкой OLD.weeks = znachenie, чтобы вставлялось уже исправленное значение.

Comment: Не понимаю как( можно примерчиком?) И мне же нужно чтобы weeks обсчитывался с поля date

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER `insert_date`
before INSERT ON `vizits` FOR EACH ROW begin
set new.weeks = 100500
end;